# how to add google webkit using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webkit

I need to add google webkit functionality to my application. I want something similar to what we have in gmail right now, where once we place the mouse over "+" symbol, it expands and provides us with various options like "insert photos', "insert links" etc. I am new to angularjs and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a custom directive for the `mouseover`, start there.

Comment: any examples that you are aware of where someone has implemented webkit??!

Comment: Haven't seen GWT used with Angular, usually its one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJGeK9zyTfOk4quVgHjk?p=preview) [ngMouseover](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angMouseover), [ngMouseleave](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angMouseleave) and [ngGlass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) for simple effect:

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <div class="menu" data-ng-controller="MenuController">
            <div class="button" data-ng-mouseover="expand($event)" data-ng-class="{hidden:expanded}">
                +
            </div>
            <div class="button-shell" data-ng-class="{expanded:expanded}" data-ng-mouseleave="collapse($event)">
                <div class="button">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*JS*

```
var m = angular.module('demoApp', []);

m.controller('MenuController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.expanded = false;

    $scope.expand = function(event){
        $scope.expanded = true;
    }

    $scope.collapse = function(event){
        $scope.expanded = false;
    }
}]);
```

*CSS*

```
.menu {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    height: 31px;

    cursor: pointer;
}

.button-shell {
    height: 31px;
    display: none;
}

.button {
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;

    line-height: 31px;
    text-align: center;

    display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.expanded {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJGeK9zyTfOk4quVgHjk?p=preview) for a demo

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave, a simple directive such as this

```
myApp.directive('expando', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.open = false;
    }],
    link: function ($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        $scope.toggleState = function () {
            if ($scope.open) {
                $scope.open = false;
            } else {
                $scope.open = true;
            }
        };
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-mouseenter="toggleState()" ng-mouseleave="toggleState()"> <span ng-hide="open" class="sectionIndicator">+</span> <div ng-show="open" class="inline" ng-transclude></div> </div>'
};});
```

would probably do what you need.
Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LukeMaso/LwFws/